# Neos inaccessible after installing

Tags: neoscms

I've installed Neos 1.1.2. After setting up the database, and importing the example "TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org", the setup seems to be completed: "You have successfully installed Neos! If you need help getting started, please refer to the Neos documentation."

But I couldn't reach a proper frontend/backend page. After clicking the buttons "go to the frontend" or "go to the backend" a new page opened with the following warning messages:

> Warning: you used the outdated TypoScript object type
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template at "landingPage/headerComment".  Please use
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template instead or TYPO3.Neos:Content if you're creating a
>   content element. Warning: you used the outdated TypoScript object type
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template at "landingPage/head/neosBackendHeader". Please
>   use TYPO3.Neos:Template instead or TYPO3.Neos:Content if you're
>   creating a content element. Warning: you used the outdated TypoScript
>   object type TYPO3.Neos:Template at
>   "landingPage/head/neosBackendEndpoints". Please use
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template instead or TYPO3.Neos:Content if you're creating a
>   content element. Warning: you used the outdated TypoScript object type
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template at "landingPage/body". Please use
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template instead or TYPO3.Neos:Content if you're creating a
>   content element. Warning: you used the outdated TypoScript object type
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template at "landingPage/neosBackendContainer". Please use
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template instead or TYPO3.Neos:Content if you're creating a
>   content element. Warning: you used the outdated TypoScript object type
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template at "landingPage/neosBackendFooter". Please use
>   TYPO3.Neos:Template instead or TYPO3.Neos:Content if you're creating a
>   content element.

Any ideas? Help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in new release.

Go directly to the backend via http://yourdomain.com/neos

If this does not work clear the cache files and cache tables.

Make sure that you use the right PHP and MySQL versions and that the filesystem of Neos install has 770 rights.

Comment: I can access the login screen of the backend http://yourdomain.com/neos but after login http://yourdomain.com/@user-admin, the same page and warnings show up. PHP 5.4.34 and mysql 5.5.40 are installed. sure, 770 was set. Can't find any cache files/tables, maybe they aren't exist yet?

Comment: Seems there went something wrong while installing neos.

Comment: Yes maybe it's a bug. After overwriting all files with neos 1.1.1 everything is fine.